# Converting from half-width katakana to full-width katakana

Tags: java, unicode

I need to convert halfwidth katakana characters to fullwidth characters.

Example:

- String "ｶﾀｶﾅ" (U+FF76 U+FF80 U+FF76 U+FF85)
- Convert to "カタカナ" (U+30AB U+30BF U+30AB U+30CA)

How can I do this in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are talking about converting "half-width Katakana" Unicode code-points to their regular equivalents.

See here for info, including a listing of the relevant code point values:

- https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/languages/asia/japanese/katakanachart/ - scroll all the way down for the half-width codes.

I don't know if there is a recommended way to do it (e.g. a standard API or 3rd-party library), but you could easily write some code to:

- put the text to a `StringBuilder`
- iterate the character positions in the builder

  - fetch the character from the builder
  - identify the half-width katakana characters (by doing a range check)
  - map the to full-width equivalents (by adding an offset ... or using a `Map`)
  - update character in the builder
- Use the contents of the updated builder; e.g. turn it into a `String`.

Comment: Looking at the code charts, I don’t think an offset will work—it needs to be a map.

Comment: Why do you need example code?  My description should be sufficient for a moderately competent Java developer to code from.  If not, please say what part you don't understand.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the icu4j library. It supports [a number of transliterations](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-are-the-system-transliterators-available-with-icu4j.html), including `Halfwidth-Fullwidth` and `Fullwidth-Halfwidth`.

Example:

```
Transliterator t = Transliterator.getInstance("Halfwidth-Fullwidth");
String result = t.transliterate(original);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use just standard API (java.text.Normalizer).
No need 3rd party solution or dependency.

It converts full-width alphanumeric characters to half-width and half-width katakana to full-width katakana

```
Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFKC)
```